# Atomic copy-and-clear on Java collection

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency

I know similar questions are often asked, but I could not find anything that would help me.

The situation is like this:

- One worker is adding elements to collection
- The second one is waiting for some time (maturity of elements) or for certain size of collection, and start it's job.

The thing is: how to copy (I think it's best to work on copy) the collection for second worker, and then clear original collection to ensure we won't lost anything (the first worker is writing all the time) but not to hold lock on original collection as short as possible?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by copy?  A deep copy or shallow copy?

Comment: Can't you just pass the reference of the "full" collection to the second worker and have the "producer" use a new collection?

Comment: @DanMatthews-Grout: I'm not a fan of "deep copy" and "shallow copy" terms, but for the needs of this question lets assume deep copy. Of course I can use `tmp = old_collection; old_collection = new Collection; return tmp;` but I'm not sure it's the best way.

Comment: @Fidor: That's exactly what I am doing right now. but is it the best way?

Comment: "Copying" java objects is generally a difficult topic; especially in any "reasonable size" project; where you might be dealing with all kinds of nested data structures. I guess you might be better of with simply "moving" the ownership of the map to the second worker; and the first worker starting with a fresh one.

Comment: As Jaegermeister says, deep copy is a hard thing to do.  You have two problems here - one is the copy mechanism and the second is signalling a worker.  The first needs clarifying - are you creating a new collection with the same objects or a new collection with new objects identical to the first collection of objects?

Comment: From my point of view, the fact if these are **the same** objects of **equal** objects is not making any changes. But it's super important that no object is lost. Right now I just have: `private synchronized Set<Object> moveOwnershipOfSet() {
  Set<Object> tmp = files;
  files = new HashSet<Object>();
  return tmp;
 }` Is it enough to ensure nothing will be lost?

Comment: Is this any more complicated than just protecting the collection with a mutex?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you are trying to achieve?
As i get, basically you've got two threads, one is a producer, another is a consumer, they share the same collections they work with.
Why not use concurrent collections, like LinkedBlockerQueue?

Comment: @jameslarge it slows the app down too much. 

crew4ok this is good idea, I'll give it a try and see what the performance will be. What I thy to achive is to make packeges of object, so I do not want my consumer to consume any time he is ready, but when buffer has enough objects or when they are in the collections for too long already.

Comment: Given a choice of either slow-but-correct or fast-but-wrong, I'd go with the former every time.  The LinkedBlockingQueue suggested by @crew4ok _is_ protected by a mutex (as any blocking queue must be).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This kind of thing will be far easier if you use the purpose-built concurrency tools like [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) rather than a plain `HashSet`.  Have the producer add elements to the queue, and the consumer can use [`drainTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#drainTo(java.util.Collection,%20int)) to extract elements from the queue in batches as it requires them.  There's no need for any synchronization, as `BlockingQueue` implementations are designed to be threadsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Ian's [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) solution is the simplest.

For higher throughput (potentially trade off with latency) in a single producer single consumer scenario, you may want to consider the example in [`java.util.concurrent.Exchanger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html)

After swapping, you now have the whole collection yourself.

Answer (score -1):

works for me

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class MyClass {

  private final Map<String, Integer> cachedData = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
  private final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
  private final Lock sharedLock = lock.readLock();
  private final Lock copyAndFlushLock = lock.writeLock();

  public void putData(String key, Integer value) {
    try {
      sharedLock.lock();
      cachedData.put(key, value);
    } finally {
      sharedLock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public Collection<Integer> copyAndFlush() {
    try {
      copyAndFlushLock.lock();

      Collection<Integer> values = cachedData.values();
      cachedData.clear();

      return values;
    } finally {
      copyAndFlushLock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```